# Using an If condition inside SPSS syntax

Tags: spss, aggregation

I have a data table where I need to calculate the number of days each user performs an action.
The structure is like this.

```
UserID       Date      TimesActionDone
  A        20110601        3
  A        20110605        0
  A        20110609        10
  B        20110701        0
  B        20110710        0
  B        20110801        1
  C        20110801        0
```

So, the result will be

```
  UserID     Days
    A          2
    B          1
    C          0
```

This is because TimesActionDone was 0 for one day for A and two days for B and C is zero. These days should not be counted. How can this be done in SPSS syntax?

```
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE=* 
  /BREAK= UserID Date      
 /N_BREAK=N
 /TimesActionDone =sum(number_of_actions).
```

This generates the first table. How do I get to the second? I have gone as far as this but doesn't work.

```
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE=* 
  /BREAK= UserID 
  IF(TimesActionDone > 0  ).
 /N_user_days=N.
```

I have not much knowledge of SPSS syntax and couldn't find much to go with my searching online. I know I can do this by removing all the cases where TimeActionDone is 0 first and then do the calculation but then I would loose information about user C. I also need to have this as 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to recode all values in TimesActionDone except 0 into 1 and then aggregate sum of this variable by userid:

```
RECODE TimesActionDone (0=0)(else=1).
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE= *
  /BREAK= UserId
  /Days= sum(TimesActionDone).
```